# What is using 20GB of memory & why doesn't it show up in task manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

Overnight, some unknown memory leak clogged up 20GB/24GB on my system. I've closed everything yet the leak persists. Running latest Windows 10.

How can I track down what is causing it?

- All software up-to-date
- No other users ever use this system
- Nothing stands out in task manager
- Nothing using too much CPU

[image: 20GB & List]

Comment: Good ol' memory leaks!

Answer (score 3):

Lucked out on finding the culprit - ended up uninstalling `Logitech Media Server` (wasn't even running anymore) and after that, the 20GB slowly dwindled down to 5.5GB.

Comment: So strange that it would freak out and suck up memory like that, but it's the unlikely things that do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact same symptoms, but in my case it was Catalyst Control Center (CCC).

As the OP mentions, Task Manager does not show the memory leak but Resource Monitor did in my case. I found that the CCC had a "Commit (KB)" of ~41,000,000 on a PC that only has 16GB of RAM. I killed that process and my RAM usage went back to normal.